# silentScroll will be undone after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

After my jQuery mobile site is loaded, I like to scroll to the position of a div. Works using this code

```
function changeViewport(){
          var errorMsg = $('.dataerror').first();
          if(errorMsg != null) {
              var newPosition = errorMsg.offset();
              $.mobile.silentScroll(newPosition.top);
          }
    }
```

I call the function on `$(document).ready`, but after calling the function and silentScroll to the position it seems the framework autoscroll back to the top of the page... Anyone know how to prevent this behaviour? (I also tried events pageinit, pageshow...)
Do I have to overwrite a function or trigger another event? Any help or suggestion is welcome :)

cheers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jquery-mobile, but it looks like this might lead you to an answer: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Comment: Any clue which property to set?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this myself, I seem to have found the cause as well as a workaround.  It appears that the animation used in *changePage* is taking precidence over the silent scroll.  You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3461).  On the same page, the comments also begin to discuss different events, such as *pagebeforeshow* or *pageaftershow* - unfortunately these yielded no results for me.

The workaround I have found was to wrap the *.silentScroll* in a timeout of a half a second.  It looks a bit choppy, but it seems to be working for me.  Hope this helps.

**Try This:**

```
function changeViewport(){
      var errorMsg = $('.dataerror').first();
      if(errorMsg != null) {
          var newPosition = errorMsg.offset();
          setTimeout(function(){$.mobile.silentScroll(newPosition.top)}, 500);
      }
}
```